# I want to create an AI like Minecraft villager

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to make an AI like Minecraft villager. Currently I use NavMesh to move objects. But this NavMesh is only a plane, not a solid.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTyCD.jpg

I changed the values ​​of Navigation and the series of NavMesh components.
On the left side of the image above, the two cube objects are not baked. Therefore, you can not put Agent on it. This is reality.
The right side of the image is ideal. If the height of one object, you can jump and get on. This is what I want to do.

Attach to agent object.

```
    void Update()
    {
        GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>().SetDestination(Player.transform.position);
    }
```

I just want the agent to chase myself.
The agent chases me, but when I stand on an object like an image, it penetrates the objects and comes directly below me.